# Why is FastNoiseLite producing oddly-tiled output?

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm trying to use `FastNoiseLite` to create heightmaps for procedurally-generated terrain. I'm generating the noise in chunks so that I can do infinite terrain generation. I'm running into this weird bug where the noise it outputs has weird tiling in the output. It doesn't at all look like the smooth noise map I'd expect (I'm expecting something more like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise#/media/File:SimplexNoise2D.png)).

Here's a minimum reproducible code example (Using Godot 4.1.1 on W11):

```
extends Node

# Set this to true to save individual heightmap files
const save_individual_heightmaps := false

func _ready():
    # Initialize noise
    var noise = FastNoiseLite.new()
    noise.noise_type = FastNoiseLite.TYPE_SIMPLEX
    
    # Initialize full image
    DirAccess.make_dir_absolute("res://heightmap")
    var full_img = Image.create(64, 64, false, Image.FORMAT_L8)
    
    # Create and save a heightmap for each sector in range
    for x in range(-32, 32, 16):
        for z in range(-32, 32, 16):
            # Create heightmap
            noise.offset = Vector3(x, z, 0)
            var heightmap = noise.get_seamless_image(16, 16)
            
            # Save individual file (if desired)
            if save_individual_heightmaps:
                heightmap.save_png("res://heightmap/" + str(x) + "_" + str(z) + ".png")
            
            # Fill in appropriate seciton of full image
            var src_rect = Rect2i(0, 0, 16, 16).abs()
            var dst = Vector2i(x + 32, z + 32)
            full_img.blit_rect(heightmap, src_rect, dst)
    
    # Save full image
    var path = "res://heightmap/full_img.png"
    full_img.save_png(path)
    
    print("Done! File saved at " + ProjectSettings.globalize_path(path))
```

Here's what the output of that code looks like:

[image]

An individual 16x16 tile looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?